# Why does adding a tokenbf_v2 index to my Clickhouse table not have any effect

Tags: indexing, clickhouse, bloom-filter

I have a large table in Clickhouse with one column called 'Route' which is a comma separated String of id's. It looks e.g. like this: `123421,25245,346263`. There can be hundreds of id's in one string.

The table is queried to select Routes that go through certain id's where the order matters, like this:

```
SELECT * FROM MY_TABLE WHERE Route LIKE '%123421%346263%'
```

Since the queries can be quite slow, I tried to speed it up by adding a data skipping index on the Route column. The tokenbf_v2 index seemed like made for my purpose, because as I understand it, it is supposed to break up my Route column into tokens and should help speeding up LIKE queries, according to the Clickhouse documentation.

However when I add the index with:

```
alter table MY_TABLE add INDEX route_index (Route) TYPE tokenbf_v1(256, 5, 0) GRANULARITY 1;
```

, and make sure it is created by running

```
OPTIMIZE TABLE MY_TABLE FINAL;
```

there is no speed up at all.

When I analyse the trace of my query in clickhouse client, it consistently shows:

```
Index `route_index` has dropped 0 granules.
```

Clearly my bloomfilter tokenbf index has no effect. Does anybody no why?

By the way, my Route column has type `String` and the granularity of table `MY_TABLE` is 128.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

like actually can work

https://github.com/ClickHouse/ClickHouse/issues/15835#issuecomment-706711503

```
select Count(*) from MY_TABLE where Route like '%,3119550599,%'
Index `route_index` has dropped 781655 / 782032 granules.
```

Answer (score 1):

To guarantee to apply the index to all data need to re-insert them all. I would recommend creating the test table with the required index and partially fill it. To use it as a playground to find more optimal indexes.

---

Consider to use *hasToken*-function or others ones allowed to *tokenbf_v1*-index (see [Skipping index: functions support](https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/engines/table-engines/mergetree-family/mergetree/#functions-support)):

```sql
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT * 
  FROM MY_TABLE 
  WHERE hasToken(Route, '123421') AND hasToken(Route, '346263'))
WHERE Route LIKE '%123421,346263%'
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Your suggestion for hasToken is right, this kicks in the notkenbf index: 

Index `route_index` has dropped 254959 granules.

However, the bloomfilter does not speed up my query but actually slows it down!

SELECT Count(*) FROM MY_TABLE WHERE hasToken(Route, '346263') 

takes 10 seconds, but

SELECT Count(*) FROM MY_TABLE WHERE Route LIKE '%346263%' 

takes 6 seconds even though this doesn't use the index!

According to the query trace, the ntokenbf index is dropping most rows. But then it for some reason scans all the rows in the table anyway ...